# C# Sorting using Delegate

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm new to C# & having trouble wi/ this current assignment.  I need to use a Delegate to sort Sort the employees by social security number in descending order and by last name in ascending order.  If anyone can just point me in how to get started it will help greatly.  This is just the employee class, but if needed, I can post all the classes.

```
using System;
// Fig. 12.4: Employee.cs
// Employee abstract base class.
using System.Text;
public abstract class Employee : IPayable
{
   // read-only property that gets employee's first name
   public string FirstName { get; private set; }

   // read-only property that gets employee's last name
   public string LastName { get; private set; }

   // read-only property that gets employee's social security number
   public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; private set; }

   // three-parameter constructor
   public Employee( string first, string last, string ssn )
   {
      FirstName = first;
      LastName = last;
      SocialSecurityNumber = ssn;
   } // end three-parameter Employee constructor

   // return string representation of Employee object, using properties
   public override string ToString()
   {
      return string.Format( "{0} {1}\nsocial security number: {2}",
         FirstName, LastName, SocialSecurityNumber );
   } // end method ToString


   // abstract method overridden by derived classes
   public abstract decimal GetPaymentAmount(); // no implementation here
} // end abstract class Employee


// Fig. 12.15: PayableInterfaceTest.cs
// Tests interface IPayable with disparate classes.
using System;

public class PayableInterfaceTest
{
   public static void Main( string[] args )
   {
      // create four-element IPayable array
      IPayable[] payableObjects = new IPayable[8];

      // populate array with objects that implement IPayable
      payableObjects[0] = new SalariedEmployee("John", "Smith", "111-11-1111", 700M);
      payableObjects[1] = new SalariedEmployee("Antonio", "Smith", "555-55-5555", 800M);
      payableObjects[2] = new SalariedEmployee("Victor", "Smith", "444-44-4444", 600M);
      payableObjects[3] = new HourlyEmployee("Karen", "Price", "222-22-2222", 16.75M, 40M);
      payableObjects[4] = new HourlyEmployee("Ruben", "Zamora", "666-66-6666", 20.00M, 40M);
      payableObjects[5] = new CommissionEmployee("Sue", "Jones", "333-33-3333", 10000M, .06M);
      payableObjects[6] = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee("Bob", "Lewis", "777-77-7777", 5000M,     .04M, 300M);
      payableObjects[7] = new BasePlusCommissionEmployee("Lee", "Duarte", "888-88-888", 5000M,     .04M, 300M);

  Console.WriteLine(
     "Lab 2 output:\n" );

  // generically process each element in array payableObjectsWW
  foreach ( var currentPayable in payableObjects )
  {
     // output currentPayable and its appropriate payment amount
     Console.WriteLine( "payment due {0}: {1:C}\n", 
        currentPayable, currentPayable.GetPaymentAmount() );
      } // end foreach
   } // end Main
} // end class PayableInterfaceTest
```

Comment: What version of .NET Framework you are using?

Comment: What's the point of commenting everything if the comments aren't even correct? "create four-element IPayable array" which clearly has 8 elements.

Comment: Didn't even notice that.  Had it originally as 4, then switched to 8.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `LINQ` ?

```
var sortedArray = payableObjects
                  .OrderByDescending(e => e.SocialSecurityNumber)
                  .ThenBy(e => e.LastName) 
                  .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Array.Sort(T[], delegate int(T, T)) is probably what you're looking for.

Call Array.Sort with your array as the first parameter, and create a function in your Employee that fills delegate int(Employee, Employee). If I recall correctly, that function needs to return 0 if they are equal, a negative number if the first comes first ascending, and a positive number if the first comes second ascending.

Comment: `Array.Sort<T> Method (T[], Comparison<T>)` is the signature you're talking about.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cxt053xf(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I'm really not sure how to create the function in the Employee class.  I have almost the same exact program in Java, but it's hard trying to convert it to C#.  This is the function I have for it in Java:

Comment: ''public int compareTo(Object o) {
  Employee e = (Employee) o;
  StringBuilder total1 = new StringBuilder(e.getidNumber());
  StringBuilder total2 = new StringBuilder(this.getidNumber());
  int ssnTotal1 = Integer.parseInt(total1.substring(0, 3));
  int ssnTotal2 = Integer.parseInt(total2.substring(0, 3));
  if (ssnTotal1 > ssnTotal2)
   return -1;
  else if (ssnTotal1 < ssnTotal2)
   return 1;
  else
   return 0;
 }
'

Comment: I think I can figure it out, but I have a hard time parsing the SSN string to int, then using substring to compare the first 3 numbers of the SSN.

Comment: The first three digits of a SSN are going to sort in the same order treated as integers or strings.

Comment: Not sure if this is correct though.  Converting the SSN to int, but wouldn't the hyphen after the first 3 numbers mess it up?        public int compareTo(Object o)
   {
       Employee e = (Employee)o;
       StringBuilder total1 = new StringBuilder(e.SocialSecurityNumber);
       StringBuilder total2 = new StringBuilder(this.SocialSecurityNumber);
       int ssnTotal1 = Convert.ToInt32(total1);
       int ssnTotal2 = Convert.ToInt32(total2);
       if (ssnTotal1 > ssnTotal2)
           return -1;
       else if (ssnTotal1 < ssnTotal2)
           return 1;
       else
           return 0;
   }

Comment: I am also getting the error of "Cannot convert from 'IPayable' to 'System.Array'

Answer (score 0):

```
       //to order by SSN desc
        foreach (var e in payableObjects.OrderByDescending(e => e.SocialSecurityNumber))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName + " " + e.SocialSecurityNumber);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("");

        //to order by Lastname Asc
        foreach (var e in payableObjects.OrderBy(e => e.LastName))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName + " " + e.SocialSecurityNumber);
        }
```